# Mixed Content error because of Keycloak default login redirection

Tags: spring, openshift, keycloak

**INFORMATION NEEDED:**

I use Keycloak (Docker version) behind a Spring project.

(The client side of this project is React and communication between client and backend is provided by REST services.)

The client side is secured and using "https" scheme.

It is my Spring configuration:

```
  keycloak:
     auth-server-url: https://sso-ssoha.b9ad.pro-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com/auth
     realm: master
     resource: clientname
     public-client: true
```

**THE ROOT OF THE PROBLEM:**

When I click a link from client, it calls a Spring service normally.
But before that, it redirects to default login page of Keycloak with adding this path **sso/login** to the current "https" url but changing scheme to "http".

**But, redirecting from https to http create a problem like this:**

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.helpful.army/contents/Problem' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://serviceha-helpfularmy.b9ad.pro-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com/sso/login'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Comment: Do you have reverse proxy on the way to Keycloak? Does it set X-Forwarded-Proto correctly? We've got problem with that, but I can't remember what error did we get then and if your case can be similar...

Comment: I think you have a point. Because, client side is React running on NGINX with a default server config is like this:
 events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    server {
        listen 3000;
        server_name www.helpful.army;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
        location ~ \.css {
            add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
        }
        location ~ \.js {
            add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
        }
    }
}

Comment: Oke 9ilsdx, I have solved it with your help. Wrote the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

it seems that we need let keycloak web server aware of we are using proxy, https://serverfault.com/questions/1000567/keycloak-blank-page-behind-nginx-reverse-proxy, after set PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING variable, it works.

Answer (score 2):

In newer version of keycloak you can configure the `proxy` setting with the value `passthrough`. In the case of docker, you want to pass the setting via the environement variable `KC_PROXY=passthrough` ([keycloack config docs](https://www.keycloak.org/server/configuration#_configuration_commands_and_stages)).

Comment: Are you saying thanks or is there a relevant additional contribution in the slightly different `KC_PROXY` != `proxy`? In the latter case pleas explain its relevance and effect.

Comment: `proxy` is the settings for the configuration file, but it can also be provided through environnement variables by prefixing with `KC_`  [Keycloak config doc](https://www.keycloak.org/server/configuration#_configuration_commands_and_stages) (I am not allowed to add a comment to exody's answer)

Comment: The explanation makes clear that there IS a contribution in your post. Please [edit] to make that more obvious. Try for [answer]. Otherwise however, if you want to comment while you do not yet have the commenting privilege - please don't. And especially do not misuse an answering post for working around the lack of commenting privilege.

Comment: Please [edit] again to keep the reference to the answer you are building on, to give credit where it is due.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem and similar ones with these steps:

**(1) Frontend side:**

You know, [www.helpful.army](https://www.helpful.army) is an educational project which has an interface running on React and it is in NGINX server.
So, I appended the default NGINX server config with mandatory headers:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        **add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;**

    }
```

**(2) Backend side:**

*I have created a different client on Keycloak just for the Spring-Boot backend and set is as a "Bearer-only" one.*

```
keycloak:
 auth-server-url: https://sso-ssoha.b9ad.pro-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com/auth
 realm: master
 resource: serviceha
 bearer-only: true
 ssl-required: "external"
 confidential-port: 0
 verify-token-audience: true
```

*I also add this configuration for application.yml:*

```
 server:
    port: 8443
    remote_ip_header: x-forwarded-for
    protocol_header: x-forwarded-proto
    use-forward-headers: true
```

**(3) I have changed all ports from interface to backend as 8443**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I migrated to Keycloak X. Starting from Keycloak 17, there is no setting for **PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING**.
For me setting the **proxy=passthrough** helped.Check https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you new to Keycloak as I am, the easiest way I found to fix this error is:

1. Go to *Administration Console -> Realm settings -> General -> Frontend URL*
2. Set `https://my.keycloak.domain/auth`

Don't forget to clear the cache when checking.

I found this solution [here](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/keycloak-in-docker-behind-reverse-proxy/1195/16)

Comment: How do you get to the administration console if you can't get to the administration console because of the mixed content error?

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak has documentation on setting up a reverse proxy https://www.keycloak.org/server/reverseproxy

In it, they explain:

> By default, the administration console URLs are created solely based on the requests to resolve the proper scheme, host name, and port. For instance, if you are using the edge proxy mode and your proxy is misconfigured, backend requests from your TLS termination proxy are going to use plain HTTP and potentially cause the administration console from being accessible because URLs are going to be created using the http scheme and the proxy does not support plain HTTP.

> In order to proper expose the administration console, you should make sure that your proxy is setting the X-Forwarded-* headers herein mentioned in order to create URLs using the scheme, host name, and port, being exposed by your proxy.

Main points are:

- Use `KC_PROXY=edge`
- Make sure the reverse proxy is sending `X-Forwarded-*` headers